# AWS API Gateway - HTTP Proxy for Elastic Beans Talk does not Passthrough responses

Tags: java, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I'm using API Gateway to decouple my Tomcat Backend in Elastic BeansTalk but I'm having trouble to get the responses from API.

The integration request works fine when I try to test using API Gateway console. It also is working fine in the backend. I make the request using the API endpoint and check the server logs and it is giving the expected 200 response.

But when API gateway fowards the response for the agent, it can not be parsed in any client. I tried using web browsers, API Test tools and mobile clients (iOS). In each case the agent tells that he "Cannot decode raw data"! I checked the endpoint using curl and it works fine. Comparing the responses from API  Gateway and Elastic BeansTalk endpoint the only difference is that in the API Gateway response the Content-Size informed is one byte longer.

Doing some research, some people on web found the same problem, with different backend services and different agents. For example, [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1226486?tstart=0) someone tells about the same problem ocurring when Safari tries to access Flickr. In the response of this question, someone tolds the problem is related to the Http Via header inserted by server.

I checked the response headers of API Gateway and indeed it has a Via Header informing that the response was served by Cloudfront. I looked for options to disable this option to test if this is the problem. But did'nt find!

So.. my questions are:

1. Someone is having or had the same problem?
2. Someone can tell me if the problem is related to the Via Http Header?
3. Can I disable this header in API Gateway? In case of yes, how??

Comment: Are you using the iOS generated SDK from API Gateway?

Comment: No!! I’m using the http session objects from foundations package. I did have huge problems with iOS sdk and just give up... mainly related to Cognito...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I disable this header in API Gateway? In case of yes, how??

Unfortunately, you can't disable the header. If you use the `REGIONAL` endpoint type (rather than `EDGE`) then the Via headers will not be added, but then you are also losing the benefits of the `EDGE` endpoint.